# Compaction while insertion Mysql

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have a use case to store my JSON payloads in my mysql column,as my scale is huge the data is growing like anything because my payloads are very big, mostly in KBs.

I am trying to find the best way possible to do some compaction while inserting. Mysql provides **AES_ENCRYPT**.

My question is :

> does this impact performance at large scale? Is there any other way
>   possible?

I am using InnoDB engine currently.

Comment: What's the question exactly? How to compress data? Encrypting it won't help for sure.

Comment: Dont see the relevance of JPA. Your database handles all of that itself ...

Answer (score 0):

Encryption does not reduce the size of data and potentially adds a small amount, padding with AES can add from 1 to 16 bytes. Encryption will also add the time to encrypt/decrypt, depending on the system hardware this can be a rather large hit or minimal.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. Compress the data with a method such as zip, compress or one of the dependents, depending on the data this can produce little to a substantial reduction in size, with the right data the compression can produce a ~90% reduction. This will add CPU overhead but in many cases is overall faster because there is less data read from disk.
2. Save large data in files and put the filename in the database. This is a rather standard way to handle large data with databases.

Comment: I don't think there's even a problem here at all. OP should simply use `json` field and stop premature optimization. There's even `TokuDB` storage engine that excels at compression and `json` field is efficient with its storage.

Comment: How would using JSON help? You do make a good point about premature optimization but that may not be the case here since the OP states: "data is growing like anything". That may or not be a problem.

Comment: Using `json` would: a) validate it's valid `json` in the first place b) maximum size depends on `max_allowed_packet` system variable (which is > 1MB usually), c) data stored as JSON is optimized (binary format, needs to additional parsing after initial save). It's 100% unlikely that OP will achieve anything through compression of JSON data, as MySQL compresses what it can. He'll just make a glorified text file out of it, killing any feature a database can offer to manipulate values stored. Hence, storing it as `json` will yield immediate advantages.

Comment: The part that is interesting is: "MySQL compresses what it can", I would be interested in seeing documentation on that, I have not used MySQL in many years.

Comment: I'll be accurate and won't go digging through InnoDB specifics (as compression has to be enabled) - [here's the documentation on Percona's TokuDB](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/tokudb/using_tokudb.html) (which is a drop-in replacement for InnoDB). Even without it, there's no reason to perform manual compression of the data *inside* columns if you can opt to compress tables on the storage level. That's the point I'm trying to make.

Answer (score -3):

There are different encryption and compression methods which you can use. They are available at this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress).

The main compression methods are:

```
1) AES_ENCRYPT()

3) DES_ENCRYPT()

4) ENCRYPT()

5) COMPRESS()
```

Some of them like DES_ENCRYPT, SHA1, MD5, are beign either less secure or too old like DES.

I have not seen a lot of infomration about how exactly the files are compressed so I suggest you to test between **AES_ENCRYPT()**, **ENCRYPT()** and **COMPRESS()**, and check the latency and response time of your server to figure it out.

Otherwise, as far as I know, Those methods are more used for establishing more safe communications between servers and applications for end users. I am not shure if compressing those informations will permit you to gain a lot of storage on your server.

But compared to what you said about the payload issues, It really depends on what you want to do and in what structure you are in (enterprise, small business, personal dev.)..If you are developing a small business or a personal project, **mysql** with **innoDB** is fine.. But for big projects like for enterprises etc. I suggest you to turn to **Oracle** or **SQL server** which are able to manage a lot more quantity of data (not free) or **PostgreSQL** which is under free licence.

Cheers andy

Comment: Why is Oracle, SQL server or PostgreSQL capable of managing a lot more quantity of data? That means they use some special algorithm that MySQL is unaware of, allowing them to magically use more hardware or what?

Comment: 1. Encryption does not decrease the size of the data. 2. SHA1, MD5 and all hash functions are not reversible, the original data can not be recovered. 3. DES should not be used for new work, is is no longer deemed secure, use AES, which is current, secure and potentially faster than DES on relatively new hardware.

Comment: "That means they use some special algorithm that MySQL is unaware of, allowing them to magically use more hardware or what?". Sorry but you miss the point here. That really not reflects my thoughts, but I have worked with MySQL and MySQLI a lot and I must say

Comment: What point am I missing? Apparently some database vendors are "better" than MySQL, I simply asked why. You having worked with MySQL and MySQLi (MySQLi is an interface for PHP to talk to MySQL, not the actual database) means quite literally nothing. Since you apparently know that other vendors are better, and I got this petabyte of data being handled by MySQL - naturally, I'm quite interested as I'd prefer to use the better tool. So, have at it - why are they better?